# Excel VBA : single row of dates separated into new rows for each month

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of dates (range Jan through Dec) that I have transposed into one row.

I want to separate this row of dates (by month) into new rows (one row per month).

If possible, I'd like to perform this in the same worksheet that the original row is located.
Original column of data is (C2:C54) that has been transposed to (D4:BD4).
Would like the new rows separated by month to start on D5.

I have not found anything online that keeps data in same worksheet and separates by month in new row. Hoping to find help here. All help is appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA would do the job for you, if I've understood the question correctly:

```
Sub Dt_Trans()
  'I is a numeric value that will offset each picked up date 
  'by 1 column, and is reset when a new month is picked up
  Mprev = Month(Range("D4"))
  'Loop through each cell in the range
  For Each C In Range("D4:BD4").Cells
     'If we reach a new month, set the I value back to zero 
     'so the new row starts from column D again
     If Month(C) <> Mprev Then
     I = 0
     End If
     'Offset D4 by the the month value to move down rows
     'I value to move across columns
     Range("D4").Offset(Month(C), I) = C.Value
     'Iterate I to avoid overwriting
     I = I + 1
     'Set Mprev so Month can be compared for the next cell
     Mprev = Month(C)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No worries, I've commented it now so you should be able to better understand and re-use the code in different scenarios.